# android studio page intent eroor

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to switch to another screen using intent, but the app stops working when the button works.The following error code appears:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.webtoon, PID: 27184
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.webtoon/com.example.webtoon.naver}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2115)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1762)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5407)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5365)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:583)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5751)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5704)
at com.example.webtoon.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:24)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7455)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7432)
at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28810)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
W/System: A resource failed to call close.
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27184 SIG: 9

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="네이버" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.webtoon;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , naver.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` because that tag is for questions/issues with the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The error message in the exception even tells you what to do:

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.webtoon/com.example.webtoon.naver}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml
```

Please check that you have added an `<activity>` declaration for your `Activity` in the manifest.

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare naver activity in the manifest file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Activities must always start with a capital letter.

For Example:

```
naver.java - Naver.java
```

Comment: This isn't true. It is a convention that class names begin with a capital letter, but this is not a requirement.